# multiple server calls with knockout js

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout-3.0

I'm learning Knockout and I would like to make multiple server calls to different urls. I don't know much about Knockout, but I do know you cannot, and should not use the applyBinding multiple times, so I have the following:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: data2().user, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">User</h2>
<h2 data-bind="text: data2().id">ID</h2>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: user, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"               placeholder="text goes here" />

<div data-bind="foreach: data1()">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: count"></div>
</div>


<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var viewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.data1 = $.getJSON('http://localhost:57635/api/Stats/GetAllStats', function (data) {
                name: data.Name;
                count: data.Count
            });
            self.data2 = $.getJSON('http://localhost:57635/api/Stats/GetItem', function        (data) {
                user: ko.observable(data.ItemName);
                id: data.Id
            });
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel)         
    </script>
```

It would be very much appreciated if anyone could give a step in the right direction or a fix.

The error in the console I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return data2().user }"
Message: object is not a function
```

Kind regards

James

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about not using the applyBinding multiple times on the same DOM element. It will throw an exception if you do that.

As for the "Unable to process binding.." error you are getting, looking at the error message, it tells you that you are treating data2 -which is an object- as a function.
The reason for this is that data2 is the return value of the $.getJSON function, which is an object. And it is also not observable if you don't define it as an observable.

So try dropping the () at: `<h2 data-bind="text: data2().user, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">User</h2>`. Use this instead: `<h2 data-bind="text: data2.user, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">User</h2>`.
I hope this helps